# Render an array with JSONAPI and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I am using jsonapi to render an object:

```
product = Product.find(1)
render json: ProductSerializer.new(product)
```

My question is, how should I serialize a list of products?

If I do this:

```
products = Product.all
render json: ProductSerializer.new(products)
```

It doesn't work, I get this error (which makes sense because I am trying to serialize an array and it doesn't have an id):

> id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec

And If I serialize each product and return it in an array, like this:

```
response = []
products = Product.all
products.each do |product| 
  response << ProductSerializer.new(product)
end
```

Each object will have an `included` object, instead of having just one `included` appended to the response with all relationships...

And this is the `ProductSerializer`:

```
class ProjectSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  
  set_type :product
  
  attributes :name
end
```

Comment: Which JSONAPI gem are you using (e.g., `jsonapi-serializer`, `jsonapi-rails`, etc.)? All the common ones should handle an array of objects to serialize just fine. Can you add the code for `ProductSerializer` to your question? There might be something to do with your serializer itself.

Comment: I was trying to use `jsonapi-serializer`, and the `ProductSerializer` is as simple as you can imagine, I just updated the post. In theory, I was suppose to use `.serializable_hash` to serialize a collection, like `ProductSerializer.new(products, { include: [:tags] }).serializable_hash`, but it doesn't work either. Serializing just one document works just fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you see using `jsonapi-serializer` v2.2.0. (I assume `ProjectSerializer` is a typo above.) Without `has_many :tags` in the serializer, I do get an error when using `include: [:tags]` since it validates there's an association, but otherwise it is happy to take an array of `Product`.

Comment: Actually, I made the assumption `:tags` are an associated record type (i.e., a product `has_many :tags`) but is that true? Looking at the code, the gem will raise the `MandatoryField` error if any included records don't respond to `.id` so maybe look at your tags? If you don't use `include:` can you process an array of `Product` objects?

Comment: I have tried with version `2.2.0`, and removed the relationship, so my serializer just contains an attribute `:name` and `:id`, and I am calling `ProductSerializer.new(Product.all)`, and I get the same error: `id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec`. We can forget the relationship, I am not even using it yet...

Comment: Found what was the issue. `Project.all` wasn't returning an array, but a `Project::ActiveRecord_Relation` instead. Had to convert it to an array `Project.all.to_a`. I though it should work with just `Project.all`.

Comment: btw, this an offtopic question, but what gem do you recommend to work with jsonapi and rails? also tried `jsonapi-rails` and it seems very similar